# shouldReceiveTouch on UITableViewCellContentView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uikit, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'm trying to ignore UITapGestureRecognizer taps on a UITableView with the following:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
      if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCellContentView class]]) {
          return NO; // ignore the touch
      }
      return YES; // handle the touch
}
```

It won't compile: "Use of undeclared identifier 'UITableViewCellContentView'

Undocumented class? Need to subclass? Better way to accomplish this?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This seems to do it:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    if([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
         return NO;
    }
    // UITableViewCellContentView => UITableViewCell
    if([touch.view.superview isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
         return NO;
    }
    // UITableViewCellContentView => UITableViewCellScrollView => UITableViewCell
    if([touch.view.superview.superview isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
         return NO;
    }
    return YES; // handle the touch
}
```

Comment: This is broken in ios7. touch.view.superView == UITableViewCellScrollView

Comment: As mentioned by Legolas, Broken on iOS7. As the hierarchy, changed, a fourth check is required. .superview.superview.superview must also be checked!

Comment: I catch it on `touch.view.superview.superview` on `iOS ver 7.0` => The **3rd check**...

Comment: If you need the whole table (including areas without cells present), replace UITableViewCell with UITableView instead.

Answer (score 11):

You can do this.

```
    - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
    {
        if ([NSStringFromClass([touch.view class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellContentView"]) {
            return NO;
        }else{
            return YES;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Very nice, would be nice to know more about this

Answer (score 6):

I've just came across this problem, and the following solution works on all iOS versions, without having the risk of Apple changing the view hierarchy of the tableView. Basicaly, keep a reference to your UITableView:

```
 - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
      if([touch.view isDescendantOfView:detailsTableView]) {
          return NO;
      }
      return YES;
   }

//isDescendantOfView:YES if the receiver is an immediate or distant subview of view or if view is the receiver itself; otherwise NO.
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. In iOS8 they changed the view hierarchy again of UITableView.

Comment: Should be the accepted answer. It solve the hierarchy changing problem

Answer (score 2):

Here's the swift solution for the selected answer.

I couldn't use the "MyTableView" named dependency check because I had a custom BaseViewController that many view controllers derive from. Some view controllers have a tableview, some have a collection view or both but in all cases the gesture recognizer steals their touches.

I didn't want to put this gesture handling code in every subclass, so the only way I got it working in the base class is this:

```
extension BaseViewController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
        var view = touch.view
        while view != nil {
            if view!.isKindOfClass(UICollectionView) || view!.isKindOfClass(UITableView) {
                return false
            } else {
                view = view!.superview
            }
        }
        return true
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its clear and simpler to check touch region.

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer,
                       shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {

    let point = touch.location(in: viewContentContainer)
    return !tableRules.frame.contains(point)
}
```