# UITapGestureRecognizer on UIImageView in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uitapgesturerecognizer, uitableview

I have designed a `UITableViewCell` in a .xib. The cell contains an `UIImageView` that only partially covers the cell. The behavior I am seeking is, if the user taps on the `UIImageView`, the `UIImageView`'s `UITapGestureRecognizer`'s selector gets triggered, and the `UITableViewCell` does not trigger `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. If the user taps on the `UITableViewCell` but not the `UIImageView`, then I want the opposite behavior. Right know what I'm getting is, when the user taps on the `UIImageView`, both the `UITapGestureRecognizer`'s selector and `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` get triggered. And when the user taps on just the `UITableViewCell`, everything works fine. How can I get the desired behavior? I have tried messing around with `cancelsTouchesInView` among other things.

Comment: What happens if you add this in the method triggered by your gesture recognizer?

    `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;`

Comment: You may want add a `UIButton` on top `UIImageView`.

Comment: Actually, I think the answer to this question has your solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28334216/uitableview-doesnt-get-touches-with-single-gesture-recognizer

Comment: Victor - I tried that didn't work; Tim - I also have a double tap gesture recognizer I'd like to work; Victor - as far as I can tell, that question is referring to the opposite problem I'm having. That delegate method that answer is relying on doesn't seem to allow me to dictate whether didSelectRowAtIndexPath gets called.

Comment: I'm going to try using a UITapGestureRecognizer to select the cell, I think that will work.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use gesture recognizer to the cell, instead allow userInteractionEnabled set to true for the imageView and add target to the imageView. Refer to this code:

```
yourImageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "imageTapped")
yourImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```