# didSelectItemAtIndexPath not working if using gesture in objective c

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a UIView A, and I added a UICollectionView B to A as a subView, so now view A is B's background view. Here didSelectItemAtIndexPath will get called normally at this time. But if I add a tap gesture recognizer to View A, then didSelectItemAtIndexPath won't be called.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [shouldReceiveTouch on UITableViewCellContentView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275195/shouldreceivetouch-on-uitableviewcellcontentview)

Answer (score 1):

Few things you want to check:

1. There is no `self.collectionView.allowsSelection = NO`. You want it to be YES.
2. I have done this mistake in past where I accidentally tried to overwrite `didDeselectItemAtIndexPath` instead. Make sure you aren't like me.
3. Use `[tapGestureRecognizer setCancelsTouchesInView:NO]` if it meets your purpose. It wouldn't send the cancel message and should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)testTouch:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)gesture
{
    if ([self.collectionView hitTest:[gesture locationInView:self.collectionView] 
                           withEvent:nil])
    {
        NSLog(@"testTouch in collection");
    } 
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"testTouch in collection.superview");
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *g = 
         [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                                 action:@selector(testTouch:)];
    g.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    [self.collectionView.superview addGestureRecognizer:g];
}
```